# Weblogic (java webapp) as a client talking to a server in HTTPS mode

Tags: web-services, ssl, https, weblogic

I have requirement to connect to a third party server via https url.

My java based webapp will be hosted in weblogic 9.2 server which will get information from the third party server in a https secure mode. Third party will provide me server ssl certificate which i need to install in the weblogic server.

Please let me know what is the procedure to install/import the server certificate into weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

[A quick Google search](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-bea.htm) turns up a wealth of knowledge.

Quick summary:

> 1. Copy both the Private Key and the your_domain_name.pem files into the
>      \wlserver6.0\config\mydomain directory.
> 2. Assign protections to the private key file and the
>      your_domain_name.pem files so that only the system User of WebLogic
>      Server has read privileges and all other users have no privileges to
>      access the private key file or digital certificate(s).
> 3. Configure WebLogic Server to use the SSL Protocol:
>
>    - You need to enter the following information on the SSL tab in the
>        Server Configuration window:
>    - In the Server Certificate File Name field, enter the full directory
>        location and name of the digital certificate for WebLogic Server
>        (digicertpack.pem). In the Server Key File Name field, enter the full
>        directory location and name of the private key file for WebLogic
>        Server. Make sure that SSL is enabled. Set the SSL Listen Port to 443.
>        Client Certificate Enforced should not be checked for most situations.
>        Click the Apply button to save your changes.
> 4. Reboot Weblogic Server.

Comment: @christina stewart  ..this appears to be setting up a ssl with weblogic , so that any client access the weblogic in a secured way. My question is how to add a server ssl certificate into weblogic so that weblogic can act as a client application - for example like client web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem recently, so I wanted to record the solution. Follow the steps below.

1. Export the certificate from the webservice URL through a browser.
2. Import the certificate into a trust store. Like this -

> keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore
> "TRUST STORE location" -alias "A NAME FOR THIS CERTIFICATE"
> -file "PATH TO CERTIFICATE"

3. Ensure that the truststore is referred by the Weblogic server instance. In admin console, select the server -> Keystores -> Trust (Section in the page)
4. Restart the server instance.

   This blog has very good info. http://theheat.dk/blog/?p=2059